# Change the default black background color

Tags: swift, colors, sprite-kit, background-color

I'm using `.aspectFit` in an app I'm creating, and as a result of using `.aspectFit` the entire scene doesn't fill up the screen (which is what I want). However, I would like to change the black back color to red if possible. Currently my scene background color is green and the back color is black (which must be the default).

I've done a little reading on the internet and it has been suggested that the black back color can be changed in the AppDelegate, however nothing seems to happen when I use the below code (the back color is still black).

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.window?.backgroundColor? = UIColor.red

    return true
}
```

[image]

Am I changing the wrong background color, or am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code can run smoothly but it's behind of the green color. Black color means there is no any scenes and it's default color provided by the system.

Comment: Ah, so you can't change the system color then?

Comment: Black is nicer than the red:)!

Comment: Haha yes, I'm just using the red (and green) for testing purposes.

Comment: @Jarron Did you ever find a solution to this, please?

Answer (score 1):

The scale mode `aspectFit` scales the contents equally in both dimensions and ensures that all of the scene’s contents are visible.

> The scaling factor of each dimension is calculated and the smaller of
>   the two is chosen. Each axis of the scene is scaled by the same
>   scaling factor. This guarantees that the entire scene is visible but
>   may require letterboxing in the view.

To change the background color of your scene you don't need to change the `window` color, you simply can do:

```
scene.backgroundColor = .black
```

If you want to chage the `window` background color you can do it also in your scene with:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.backgroundColor = .red
```

Comment: Hi Alessandro, thanks for your answer, but I don't need to change the scene color to red, I want to change the visible none scene area to red.

Comment: What do you mean for "visible none scene area" ? Can you explain better this part?

Comment: In the image in my question you can see black and green areas. The green area is my scene and the black is the none scene area (not sure what you would call it). The green only takes up part of the screen because I'm using aspectFit (which is what I want, but I would like to change the black color).

Comment: I want sprites to not be visible when they exit the green area, which is what happens currently. However I don't want the black color. I can achieve what I desire by creating a cropNode in an aspectFill scene, but I thought being able to change the black color in an aspectFit scene would have been the easiest option.

Comment: I have my games with `.aspectFit`, and I haven't this letterboxing effect, you should check your Xcode version (if it is the latest..) and test your project to a real device. Please report to your question more relevant code about your issue and more details about your tests.

Comment: No the letterboxing effect is intentional. Where I would usually use view.bounds.size, I'm setting the scene size to 750 x 450 and the scaleMode to .aspectFit so that the app becomes universal without bias. I'm only working within the 750 x 450, this is why the letter boxing effect doesn't bother me, just the color does.

Comment: Ah ok well, you can't. After the scene is rendered, its contents are copied into the presenting view. If the view and the scene are the same size, then the content can be directly copied into the view else the scene is scaled to fit in the view. The scaleMode property determines how the content is scaled. The letterboxing is create IN the view so there is no way to change it's color.

Comment: All good, I can achieve my desired effect another way, was just seeing if there was an easier way. Thanks!